# Retrieve hidden playlists from my own account using YouTube API without requesting password from client (.NET/C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube-api, oauth-2.0, youtube.net-api

I am trying to find a way to retrieve my own private playlists from my own personal YouTube account via a server side web app built in ASP.NET (C#). Based on the research that I have done, the consensus seems to be that my app needs to authenticate against my account with Oauth 2.0. I want my website to show a list of videos from a few playlists that I have set as hidden, and I want the list to show on a public page. For this reason, I obviously do not want to enter in my youtube account details every time that I browse the page.

I have looked and looked and there does not seem to be any clear way to do this. Some people have suggested going through the Oauth 2.0 authentication flow once, then use the code that it returns in the redirect URL to generate a refresh token, and use that token in your application; another suggestion I have read is to use an API service account. There does not seem to be any working example code available anywhere.

Has anyone had to do this same thing and have you been successful setting it up? Google's own API client library documentation is abysmal, especially for the .NET libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If the playlists are hidden you won't be able to access them without logging in.

If the playlists are public you can always query for them through the YouTube API without having to pass your credentials.

Comment: Google's own API documentation says that there is a way to do it without manually entering your account credentials. It involves generating a private key certificate and using that to authenticate your account every time your application needs authenticated API access. They call it using a "service account". What they don't give you are any good instructions on how to use this to access the YouTube API, which is what I need to do. I can't be the only one who has ever needed to do something like this.